# Convergence and divergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over{\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to decide if these series are convergent or divergent, using the comparison test, the quotient test, the integral test, or the Leibniz Theorem:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}}$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over{\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}}}$$

For the first one, I think that when $n$ is big, $1\over{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}$ is almost equal to $1\over{\sqrt[3]{n^2}}$, right? I think I can use this to do a **comparison test.** $1\over{\sqrt[3]{n^2}}$ diverges because it is equal to $1\over{n^{2/3}}$ and ${2\over3}<1$? How do I solve this; is my reasoning correct? Thanks.

Comment: Be careful not confusing a series and its general term: $\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$  DOES converge (to $0$). Convergent=to have a finite limit. It is true that   $\sum\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ diverges though

Comment: Yes, I always confuse that. It diverges because of the p-series right?

Answer (score 1):

$1\over{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}$ >${1\over n^{2/3}}=u_n$ so you can use the comparison test in fact the limit of the quotient of the general term of both series with $u_n$ is $1$, so they diverge.

Write $\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}=n^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{1-{1\over n^{2/3}}}$

$\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}=n^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{1+{1\over n^{2/3}}}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "in fact the limit of the quotient of the general term of both series with $u_n$ is $1$"? And what does $\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}=n^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{1-{1\over n^{2/3}}}$ does?

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt [3] {n^{2}-1} \leq  n^{2/3}$ for all $n >1$. Hence the first series dominates $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2/3}}$ which is divergent. Second series can be handled in a similar way. [$\sqrt [3] {n^{2}+1} \leq  2n^{2/3}$].

Comment: So $1\over{n^{2/3}} \leq 1\over{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}$, right? Why on the second one it is $2n^{2/3}$?

Comment: $\sqrt [3] {n^{2}+1} > n^{2/3}$ and this is of no  use here. But $\sqrt [3] {n^{2}+1} \leq 2n^{2/3}$ and this is useful. In both cases use the fact that $0 <a\leq b$ implies $\frac 1 a \geq \frac 1 b$.

Comment: Where did $\sqrt [3] {n^{2}+1} \leq  2n^{2/3}$ came from? Can you explain it a little bit more? I understood that for the first one $\sqrt [3] {n^{2}-1} \leq  n^{2/3}$ since its easy to see that $n^2 -1 < n^2$.

Comment: @davidllerenav $\sqrt [3] {n^{2}+1} \leq \sqrt [3] {n^{2}+n^{2}}=2^{1/3} n^{2/3} \leq 2n^{2/3}$.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. O ne question. Every time I want to use the comparison test, I need to find a series that is bigger than the one I will compare it to, right? Like you did with $\sqrt [3] {n^{2}-1} \leq  n^{2/3}$, but it doesn't matter that it will end up being $1\over{\sqrt [3] {n^{2}-1}} \geq  1\over{n^{2/3}}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \ge 2:$

$\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{n^2}} \lt \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+n^2}} \lt$

$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}} \lt \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}.$

$(1/2)\sum \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2}}$ diverges.

Hence?

Comment: Why did you set $n>2$? I understand what you did, but why did you set $n>2$ sisnce the beginning

Comment: davidleranow.n >1, since denominator cannot be zero $(n^2-1)$, so $n \ge 2$.